# JavaScript - Allowing a variable to change the background colour

Tags: javascript

i was wondering if there was a way that i could have

`document.body.style.backgroundColor = a variable`  <---something like that

so that when the variable is changed it would set the background colour to the set the colour that is set by the variable

IT has to be javascript, so keep the html to a minimum

Comment: Just FYI, perhaps you're not a native speaker, but "keep the html to a minimum" comes across quite rude in writing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bg= "red"
document.body.style.backgroundColor = bg;
```

you can change the value with the help of textbox and assign that value to bg variable

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. There's no event raised when a variable is changed, so when you change the variable, you'll *also* have to re-run your code setting the `backgroundColor`.

You could do it with an object property in ES5+ (all modern browsers; not IE8):

```
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "bg", {
    set: function(value) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = value;
    },
    get: function() {
        return document.body.style.backgroundColor;
    }
});
```

Now,

```
o.bg = "green";
```

changes the background color to green.

**Live Example:**

```js
var o = {};
Object.defineProperty(o, "bg", {
  set: function(value) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = value;
  },
  get: function() {
    return document.body.style.backgroundColor;
  }
});

var colors = ["green", "blue", "yellow"];
var index = 0;
var stopAt = Date.now() + 6000;
tick();
function tick() {
  console.log("Setting " + colors[index]);
  o.bg = colors[index];
  index = (index + 1) % colors.length;
  if (Date.now() < stopAt) {
    setTimeout(tick, 1000);
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Testing 1 2 3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have color values in a select list or can be given through input box. And on that you can bind 'onChnage' event and get that value in a variable and assign that variable to background color property.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Easiest code to change background color:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ZishanAdThandarGreen()
    {
    document.getElementById("results_container_Zishan").innerHTML = 'Green';
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = '<!-- body, html {font-family:Tahoma, Times, Times;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:green;} -->'; 
    }
    function ZishanAdThandarBlue()
    {
    document.getElementById("results_container_Zishan").innerHTML = 'Blue';
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = '<!-- body, html {font-family:Tahoma, Times, Times;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:Blue;} -->';
    }
    function ZishanAdThandarGrey()
    {
    document.getElementById("results_container_Zishan").innerHTML = 'grey';
    document.getElementById("color").innerHTML = '<!-- body, html {font-family:Tahoma, Times, Times;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:Grey;} -->';
    }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css" id="color">
    <!-- 
    body, html {font-family:Tahoma, Times, Times;width:100%;margin:0;padding:0;text-align:center;background:red;}
    -->
    </style>

        <h2>Background Color script by ZishanAdThandar</h2><br>
          Current Color:<div id="results_container_Zishan">Red</div> 
          <button id="download-json" class="btn" style="align:right;"onclick="return ZishanAdThandarGreen()">Green</button>
          <button id="download-json" class="btn" style="align:right;"onclick="return ZishanAdThandarBlue()">Blue</button>
          <button id="download-json" class="btn" style="align:right;"onclick="return ZishanAdThandarGrey()">Grey</button>  
        <br>
    </body>
```